# How are electric range drip pans measured?

Tags: range

I have an electric range and the drip pans need replaced, I've seen measurements on the new drippans but what is it that they measure?  Is it the radius, the diameter, or the circumference of the drip pan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drip pans are measured using the diameter of the hole in the range. There are many different styles so your best bet would be to take the old pan with you to your home store and get a match making sure where the electrical plug hole is located and that the burner supports will fit into the pan. You might be able to order them from the manufacturer or an appliance store.

Comment: Exactly right, there are many, many configurations e.g. deeper, shallower, notched, hole size and location, rim width, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All above considerations aside, they measure the diameter. Six and eight inch are common. Do bring yours with you to get an exact match. Home improvement stores will be cheaper than the manufacturer, appliance stores and most physical repair/parts stores, IMHO.

Comment: "Home improvement stores _may or may not_ be cheaper than the mfgr". FTFY. I recently purchased a product at a major online retailer (no, not a home improvement store, but the lesson applies) and had the privilege of paying 50% _more_ than I would have paid if I'd gone directly to the mfgr web site since I didn't bother checking around. Lesson learned. _Caveat emptor_.